# How to separate custom code from generated in RoR

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been developping a bit in .net and I'm discovering rails these days.
I'm familiar with code generation and something has seemed quite usefull in .net. It's that when we do custom code, like a new method in a Model, we do it in a separate file (with a `public partial class`) from the code that has been automatically generated.
So if we change the type of an attribute and regenerate the code, the methods we have created are not erased.

I've not found something similar in the RoR tutorials on the internet. Does it work the same or is there another solution to easily rescaffold code without erasing custom methods?

Thanks

Comment: What type of code do you generate in .NET? The ORM part?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to generate ORM related code in C#, you don't need to worry code generation problem in Rails. Thanks to the dynamic typing & meta-programming ability of Ruby and the "Convention over Configuration" philosophy in Rails, you don't need to generate ORM code with tools at all.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The above class will automatically get mapped to `products` table in the database. You can access the value of each column via accessor like `p.name`. You can retrieve products via `Product.find`, `Product.where`, etc.

These codes are injected via subclassing or mixins (as **Amir** pointed out), or more generally, generated at runtime on demand with the help of [`BasicObject#method_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing).

You can take a look at [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), and it may be helpful to go through the entire guide to experience the Rails agile development.

Comment: So, imagine if I create a class People with Gender:boolean Name:String , then in the People Model I create several methods such as 'insertPersonInCourse' ,for example, in the People Model file. It would be totally ok to launch the command to update my Model because I decided that Gender would be a string, and my custom methods will not be erased?

Comment: @Krowar The method generation happens at runtime. It won't save to the source code. For the `insertPersonInCource`, you'll find [`belongs_to` and `has_many` helpful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You may write `some_course.people << person`. Take a look at [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can do that with a `mixin` - create a `Module` and then include it in your class.

There's a lot of information about it online, check out this post [here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/)